# need help translating CTE query into linq (not recursive)

Tags: linq, common-table-expression

Not sure how easy this is to answer just by looking at a sample SQL query when you don't know the data behind it, but I'll try anyway. This is a SQL query meant to list files in a source control db--showing the source file path side-by-side with its most recent checked-in version path:

```
WITH [recentCheckins] AS (
    SELECT [SourceFileID], MAX([Version]) AS [LatestVersion]
    FROM [Checkin]
    GROUP BY [SourceFileID]     
) SELECT 
    [sf].[Path], -- current version
    [ci].[ArchivePath] -- most recent previous checkin
FROM 
    [recentCheckins] 
    INNER JOIN [SourceFile] [sf] ON [recentCheckins].[SourceFileID]=[sf].[ID]
    INNER JOIN [Checkin] [ci] ON 
        [recentCheckins].[SourceFileID]=[ci].[SourceFileID] AND
        [recentCheckins].[LatestVersion]=[ci].[Version]
```

This is the most I could do:

```
var query2 =
    from latestCheckins in (
         from checkin in _project.Checkin
         group checkin by checkin.SourceFileID into results
         select new
         {
             SourceFileID = results.Key,
             LatestCheckinVersion = results.Max(s => s.Version)
         })
         join sourceFile in _project.SourceFile on latestCheckins.SourceFileID equals sourceFile.ID
         join checkins in _project.Checkin on // fails on this line, does not like join keyword here
             new { latestCheckins.SourceFileID, latestCheckins.LatestCheckinVersion }               
                  equals new { checkins.SourceFileID, checkins.Version }
             select new
             {
                Filename = sourceFile.Path,
                CheckinDate = checkins.DateCreated,
                TaskID = checkins.TaskID,
                Comments = checkins.Comments,
                Version = latestCheckins.LatestCheckinVersion.ToString(),
                NewFile = _project.GetSourceFilename(sourceFile.Path),
                OldFile = checkins.ArchivePath,
                ID = sourceFile.ID
             };
```

Comment: The query with CTE is recursive. Linq can't do recursive queries in one statement. You'll have to query each level separately or make a view of the recursive query and use that a data source for linq.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what recursive means in the context of CTEs, but thank you I was able to solve by writing as separate queries per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got this to work by breaking it into separate queries, as suggested by Gert above.